# Items not adding to ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I just started learning C# today. And I proceed already in creating GUI since some syntax are just like Java.
Here's what I did so far:

> Click on the ComboBox in , Design tab. Then it directed me a method.
>   Inside the method, here is my code:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int days = 31;
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        this.dayComboBox.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

But it's not adding to the ComboBox. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm going on a limb to say the event might be screwing it up.

Comment: have you stepped through the code.. and when you get to the Items.Add method what are the values in `dayCoboBox` when you inspect it using the debugger.. also try changing the code to the following 
`this.dayComboBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());` see if that works also make sure that the AutoPostBack property is set to true for the ComboBox

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` is not the appropriate place to do this. You will want something like Form Load event or another button click. Double click the Form in Design view and try your code in the method that generates.

Comment: This will only happen when the selection of combobox2 change

Comment: @Crowcoder YESSSSSSSSSS It worked thank you very much (So much happiness for a beginner xD). 
Thank you also whycry and methodman :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some other code

}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int days = 31;
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        this.dayComboBox.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

`SelectedIndexChanged` never seems to be changing. Plus any time you change the index, you'll re-add all the items again. Form_Load would be better. Load it once....done.

Comment: So it means that, most of my code will be at `Form_Load();`  ?

Comment: For initializing information in your ComboBox, that would be the best option unless you want to do it with a button or something along those lines.

Comment: Got everything :D Thank you very much for your help and time :D